# Custom seekbar showing gap in between, on large screens?

Tags: android, seekbar

I made a custom seekbar using 2 png images for my android app. One image is the background, and other is the bar which shows progress. Both are of the same length and width. On small screens( ~5"), it displays perfectly. But on larger screens( ~8"), a small gap is present on the upper bar, and a small part of the lower bar is visible from that gap, as shown in picture:
[image]

I checked the 2 .png files, and there is no problem in them. Also, this gap only shows up on big screened devices. What could be causing this?

Edit: Added the XML for the seekbar area:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1333333333333333"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:contentDescription="@string/p"
    android:src="@drawable/volbar" />
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:minHeight="5dip"
    android:maxHeight="5dip"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/styled_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:thumbOffset="13.5dp" 
    android:paddingRight="13.5dp" 
    android:paddingLeft="13.5dp"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout xml file thanks

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi Added the XML for the seekbar area.

Answer (score 0):

There is a margin and a padding on your seekbar, that can explain why there is a gap between your to images...

Comment: Add the same padding & margin to the imageView as @TheBeps says and it should resolve your issue

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi The imageview is the background black area.. adding margin to it will not allow it to stretch to the full width of the device..

Comment: @thebeps : Thanks for the answer but, how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @vergilcorleone is there a reason why you have the imageview with the seekbar? you can set the seekbar to have a background image as well.

Comment: @AshwiniBhangi Removed the imageview, changed nothing. gap is still there

Comment: Try changing the padding to half of thumb offset i.e. about 7dp